# Removing [Fake]

Tags: discussion, burninate-request

There is currently a tag for [fake](/questions/tagged/fake). While looking through the questions tagged with this, I find that it is used as a synonym for [mocking](/questions/tagged/mocking), [spoof](/questions/tagged/spoof)/[spoofing](/questions/tagged/spoofing) and even [url-rewriting](/questions/tagged/url-rewriting), as well as a wide range of fake things (fake cookies, fake CA certificates, fake mouse/keyboard input, fake email-addresses, fake headers, etc). At the time of writing there are 81 questions tagged with 'fake'.

This tag seems to be solely for meta-information about a question, or it is being used when an other tag is more appropiate. I think in most cases the tag should be removed, and in specific cases it can be re-tagged with the tags above (if that wasn't done already). Then this tag should be burninated.

Comment: I went to work on removing this tag from questions and several of them  are apparently referring to an actual tool: "FAKE (F# Make)". Trying to keep the tag to that would probably be tedious, though.

Comment: Apparently "fake" is also a kind of object for testing purposes. Could tag it "fake-object" or something?

Comment: The [fake] tag seems fake.

Comment: @KevinReid There is already a [fakeo](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fakeo) tag with only one question.

Comment: @PeeHaa: feels like another for burning or at least renaming... what a mess... who review and approve, or apply these? Can we improve it somehow in the future? Perhaps, this is not a discussion for today,  so pardon me.

Comment: Everybody with > 1500 intarnets repz can create tags. It is mostly up to the community to prevent crap tags from spreading. @LaszloPapp

Comment: I know about the reputation, but still: why do people create mess with somewhat reasonable reputation level? :'( Perhaps the reputation level is too low for this?

Comment: @KevinReid I've retagged those 2 questions to [tag:f#-make]. All other questions are either retagged or now have the tag removed completely. The tag has now 0 questions and I am assuming that the tag will now be burned and deleted automatically?

Comment: @Sumurai8: unused tags are removed automatically after 24 hours.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This makes sense to me. I have just had a similar request yesterday for a similarly common tag name that became a container over time.

[Future of the [quick] tag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/198684/future-of-the-quick-tag)

That has been pretty much the same situation, as in:

- no tag wiki at all to start to understand its intention
- It was about 75 tags or so and someone went ahead and cleaned up within a few hours.

So, my personal opinion is that it would be nice to burn this one, too, or at least renaming to something more talkative with regards to unit testing.

Answer (score 0):

There are only 65 questions tagged [fake](/questions/tagged/fake) so what are you waiting for? ;-)

Only 2 followers, 65 questions, no tag wiki..., meta tag. Go for it! :D

Comment: What I am waiting for? Mostly feedback. It's the first time I even considered a removal of a tag, let alone that I know how those things normally go or if it is normal if someone would start removing tags out of nowhere. I'll first dream about it and if no-one did it already, I'll make some time to remove all references to that tag tomorrow.

Comment: @Sumurai8: actually, you have just pasted this today for discussion, and this is weekend... I would wait more than just one day to be honest...

Comment: @Sumurai8 have nice dreams about and kill it with napalm tomorrow :-) I went through the questions tagged [fake] and it deserves to be gone. So unless somebody has something against it (which I really doubt) kill it with fire.

Comment: @PeeHaa: as I said, give some time to the people. It has been around only a few hours, and it is weekend. I do not see the point in rushing and then saying this was the "wide community consensus". I would actually hold it off for a week at least to give everyone who cares enough time to raise objections.